# Regex match first email address that isn't a specified email address

Tags: regex, email

I have a string with one or more email addresses in it, I want to use a regex to find the first email address that isn't a specified email address.  For example if my string contains one or more email addresses of the general form someone@somedomain.com but also may contain one or more occurrences of a particular email address exactly equal to particularperson@anotherdomain.com, how I can find the first email address that matches the first form and that isn't the second form?  Or to put it another way, I want the first email address that isn't particularperson@anotherdomain.com.  All the email addresses could be in any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex to match **any** email address is `\w+@\w+\.\w{3}`.

Then (after this regex has just matched), you can use
a **negative lookbehind** to exclude the "forbidden" address,
e.g. `(?<!particularperson@anotherdomain\.com)`.

So the whole regex can be:

```
\w+@\w+\.\w{3}(?<!particularperson@anotherdomain\.com)
```

Of course, it is not sure, whether your flavour of regex supports negative
lookbehinds (e.g. JavaScript doesn't), but you didn't specify it.

Note: You can't use negative lookahead for the forbidden address,
and then the regex to match any address.
The reason is that after the negative lookahead matches
(finds the forbidden address), the regex processor moves one
char forward and starting the next try from this place this looakhead will
not match.
So the regex to match any address will match the forbidden
address without just the first char.

### Edit

If you have variable last part (`.co`, `.com` and others), try a little
different approach.

You can not write e.g. `.com?` in the lookbehind, because it does not allow
variable pattern length.

Insteadm you may put the negative lookbehind **before the last part**
(whatever it is) and check only for `particularperson` and `anotherdomain`
(plus `@` and `.` in the proper places).

Two more additions:

- After what you have caugt so far, there can be neither dot nor any word
  char, so the final part should be `(?!\.\w)`.
- Similarly, the whole regex should start with `\b`, to start at
  the word boudary

So the corrected regex can be:

```
\b\w+@\w+\.(?<!particularperson@anotherdomain\.)\w{2,3}(?!\.\w)
```

Comment: My application is using .NET framework RegEx classes so negative lookbehinds are supported and your answer works for me thank you!

Comment: I have found a problem in the solution, that negative lookbehind causes the regex to match to particularperson@anotherdomain.co (no trailing m), how do I make it not do that?